# Try/Catch block in PHP query

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am looking at some old legacy code written and have the following try/catch block - a number of times the name defaults to 'DEFAULTNAME' - I'm not sure why it is doing this? I presume that the try is failing (in this instance the xml stuff) & causes it to default to 'DEFAULTNAME' (not always but a fair amount)

Also...do all try/catch blocks need a 'throw' too? As this code doesn't have one anywhere?

```
$xml_element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$namespaces = $xml_element->getDocNamespaces(); 
$xml_element->registerXPathNamespace('tns', $namespaces['']); 

$re = $xml_element->xpath('///tns:IntegrationExport/tns:Data/tns:Citizen/tns:Services/tns:Service[@refinement="Pupil"]');
$re_element = $re[0];
$re_element = $re_element[0];

// xml stuff...
try
{
  // $re_element is collated from some xml/xpath query outside of the try/catch block via an API
  $name = (string)$re_element->attributes()->application;
  $name = strtolower($name);
  $name = str_replace("Name ","",$name);
  $name = trim($name);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  $name = "DEFAULTNAME";
  error_log($e->getMessage);
}
```

Comment: The only thing that could possibly fail here is `$re_element->attributes()->application`, it *may* throw an exception. Anything else will not throw an exception. However, since we have no idea what that code does, we cannot know. What's your question exactly? How exceptions work? That's bit too broad and must have been explained already somewhere.

Comment: You are probably right - i've added more code that demonstrates the $re_element and how that is generated - i'll look into the xml_element as it must be there that the error is happening i'm guessing

Comment: The developer might use a custom error handler which turns warnings into exceptions. Search the code for `set_error_handler()`

Comment: good thinking.. i will give that a shot too thanks